# The efficient code to implement this feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

In my page, I have three input fields, "**start date**", "**end date**" and "**colors**" drop-down menu,like follows:

```
<label>Start date (yyyy-mm-dd):</label>
<input id='start_date' type='text'></input>
<br>
<label>End date (yyyy-mm-dd):</label>
<input id='end_date' type='text'></input>
<br>
<label>Color:</label>
<select id="color">
    <option value="white" selected="selected">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="green">Transparent</option>
</select>
```

I would like to have the following feature for this UI:

1. If date span defined by "**start date**" and "**end date**" is a past period (i.e. <= today), the "**color**" drop-down menu should only show **'Black' and 'White'** options.
2. If date span defines a future period (>today), the "color" drop-down only show **'red' and 'green'** options.
3. If date span contain past days and future days, the "color" drop-down only show '**Transparent**' option.

How to implement this features with efficient, elegant jQuery/javascript code?

My current jQuery code:

```
$("#end_date").click(update_options())

function update_options(){
    var start_date = $("#start_date").val();
    var end_date = $("#end_date").val();

    var startDate= new Date(start_date);
    var endDate= new Date(end_date);
    var today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    if(endDate < today){
        $('#color').get(2,3,4).remove()
    }
    else if(startDate<=today && endDate>=today){
        $('#color').get(0,1,2,3).remove()
    }
    else{
        $('#color').get(0,1,4).remove()
    }

}
```

Which seems not working correctly and not elegant

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Have you tried to implement this at all or are you just looking for somebody to code it for you?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, just forgot to put my code... just a moment...:P

Answer (score 1):

Any one of these plugins might be what you're looking for.

- [Chained](http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects)
- [Dependent Select](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DependentSelect)
- [Select Chain](http://remysharp.com/2007/09/18/auto-populate-multiple-select-boxes/)
- [Related Selects](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/related-selects)