# How to get multiple options at one time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have a drop down menu:

```
<select id="color">
    <option value="white" selected="selected">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="green">Transparent</option>
</select>
```

I know in jQuery I can get a option with option index like this:

```
$('#color option:eq(2)') //get 'red'
```

But is there any way to get multiple options at a time ? I tried the following code:

```
$('#color option:eq(2, 3)') //Try to get 'Red' and 'Green'
```

and

```
$('#color option:eq([2, 3])') //Try to get 'Red' and 'Green'
```

But neither one working, how to workaround to get multiple options at a time?

Comment: Not by using `:eq`. How are you going to be deciding which indexes you need to select? Can you not iterate single `:eq` selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) if you want to get a subset of the collection.

```
$("#color option").slice(2,3)
```

If you want to get different elements you could do the following:

```
$("#color option").filter(":eq(2), :eq(4)");
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/TtdN8/).**

Comment: Might want to fix the quotes. ;)

Comment: I tried, and I found that when using slice(), the index of the option list is changed after hide some options; while using filter() will not change the index of options. In my case, filter() is preferred. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419915/the-efficient-code-to-implement-this-feature), you might want to consider adding a class to specific options. This not only allows you to grab multiple ones, but gives some context as well:

```
<select id="color">
    <option value="white" selected="selected" class="past">White</option>
    <option value="black" class="past">Black</option>
    <option value="red" class="future">Red</option>
    <option value="green" class="future">Green</option>
    <option value="green" class="mixed">Transparent</option>
</select>
```

Then, when you write your logic, you could do something like

```
$('option.future, option.multi').hide();
$('option.past').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat it like any other array once you've selected the element:

```
var opts = $('#color option')
var output = ""    
for(var x=0;x<opts.length;x++) {
    output+=" " + opts[x].value    
}
alert(output)
```